# Miner for Non-Standard Transactions

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-pools, miner-configuration, non-standard-transaction

I understand that bitcoin-core introduced the `IsStandard()` check in v0.9(?) to prevent non-standard transactions from being broadcast (unless in a mined block).

I'm interested to know whether there are any current mining pools or miners that will process non-standard transactions - i.e. they're running a non-default configuration that will permit the non-standard transactions to be submitted using `sendrawtransaction` (or another method) and mine them.

When I say non-standard, I mean that the transaction will be rejected because it contains **non-standard inputs** (i.e., inputs that return false when evaluated by `IsStandard()`).

I already understand that `testnet` is more permissive in this sense but I'm specifically interested in miners on `mainnet`.

Note: This question is for academic purposes in support a paper I am writing.

Comment: The checks in `isStandard()` are largely ignored for P2SH scripts and for Segwit scripts, since they sidestep a lot of the concerns that caused the standardness checks to come into existence.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm talking specifically about transactions that involve non-standard inputs, so P2SH\Segwit doesn't apply here. I'll edit the question to clarify what I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

> I'm interested to know whether there are any current mining pools or miners that will process non-standard transactions - i.e. they're running a non-default configuration that will permit the non-standard transactions to be submitted using sendrawtransaction (or another method) and mine them.

Yes there are some mining pools that include non-standard transactions in block.

Example: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5192454.msg55842508#msg55842508